# Can I call a rake task from PHP?

Tags: php, rake

can I run a rake task from php?
I tried shell_exec but nothing happens.

```
exec('/bin/bash -l -c \'cd /Users/username/www/rails_app && [[ -s "/Users/username/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/Users/username/.rvm/scripts/rvm/.rvm/scripts/rvm" && rvm use 2.1.2 && RAILS_ENV=development /usr/bin/rake "ko:complete_order[2]" --silent\'', $out, $err);
```

The $out is an empty array.
The $err is 1.

Comment: What were you expecting from code? It worked or didn't work?

Comment: Unfortunatelly didn't work my code.

Comment: try with ` --trace` option instead?

Comment: It's the same result.

Comment: You should have received some log, right? can you post that log?

Comment: I haven't got a log. If I call the index.php from the command line the script is running, with some errors, but running. But if I call in the browser, nothing happens.

Comment: The error code 1 is Operation not permitted.